# How to calculate percentage in sql?

Tags: sql

I have to calculate percentage based on count. Given below is a sample data table.

```
TeamName   Count1   Count0
--------   -----    ------
Team1        1        2
Team2        3        0
Team3        1        1
```

I want to display the percentage based on the `greatest value` in `Count1`. `The expecting output sample is given below:`

Expecting Out Put :

```
TeamName   Count1   Count0  Percentage1  Percentage0
--------   -----    ------  -----------  -----------
Team1        1        2        33.33%         66.6%
Team2        3        0        100%           0%
Team3        1        1        33.33%         33.33%
```

Help me to find a proper solution. Thank You.

Comment: Can you explain the output for team3? should it be 50%-50%?

Comment: I don't get Team3's Percentage1  and Percentage0. I did expect 50% for both.

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: What about case when Count1 has zero as max value?

Comment: @Mureinik there is no relation between percentage1 and percentage0. I am taking the greatest value from Count1 and calculation percentage of values in both count1 and count0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `Max()over ()` trick to find the max of all the row.

```
select TeamName,   
Count1,  
Count0,
(count1*100.0)/nullif(Max(Count1) over(),0) Percentage1,
(count0*100.0)/nullif(max(Count1) over(),0) Percentage2
from yourtable
```

or Use a `subquery` to find the `Max` and do the math

```
SELECT 
  TeamName, 
  Count1, 
  Count0, 
  (Count1*100.0) / nullif((SELECT max(Count1) FROM yourTable),0) Percentage1, 
  (Count0*100.0) / nullif((SELECT max(Count1) FROM yourTable),0) Percentage2
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: I have to find percentage based on highest value in count1 column. The above answer not taking the highest value from the column count1

Comment: @vipintp - Then use `Max` instead of `sum`. Updated check now

Comment: How to get percentage as float values, like 33.33%. Now it shows like 33% only, but the actual percentage is 33.33.

Comment: @vipintp - Which DBMS you are using

Comment: @vipintp - In `Sql Server` it will work as expected since we are using `100.0` instead of just `100` to calculate percentage.  `oracle` and `Mysql` 100 itself will give you result with decimal values. If you want i can add demo

Comment: Yes I want . Please add that also.

Comment: Thank you. Now it is working. But it showing output 33.3333333333 this much lengthy. how can I reduce it into 33.333

Comment: @vipintp - do this `cast(value as numeric(10,2)`

Comment: Can you write one example. I don't know how to apply this

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  TeamName, 
  Count1, 
  Count0, 
  Count1 / (SELECT MAX(Count1) FROM Tbl), 
  Count0 / (SELECT MAX(Count1) FROM Tbl) 
FROM Tbl
```

What out for zero values in Count1. I can improve answer, if you describe case what to do when MAX(Count1) is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you:

```
SELECT a.TeamName,
       a.Count1,
       a.Count0,
       a.Count1 / b.maxCount * 100
       a.Count0 / b.maxCount * 100
  FROM yourTable a
  JOIN(SELECT MAX(Count1) 
         FROM yourTable
      ) b
    ON 1 = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
create table tbl(teamname nvarchar(100), count1  int, count2  int)

insert into tbl values
('T1',1,2), ('T2',3,0), ('T3',1,1)

select 
    teamname,
    count1,    
    count2,
    count1 * 100 /(count1 + count2) Percenta1,
    count2 * 100 /(count1 + count2) Percenta2   

From tbl

drop table tbl
```

Answer (score -1):

looking at your question, it seems if value is 1 then it is 33.33%, for 2 it is 66.6% & for 3 it is 100%. in this case yuo can try below:

```
SELECT COUNT1, COUNT0,
DECODE(COUNT1,1,'33.33%',2,'66.6%',3,'100%') PERCENTAGE1,
DECODE(COUNT0,1,'33.33%',2,'66.6%',3,'100%') PERCENTAGE0
FROM tablename;
```

if it is not the case, then please explain why for row3 in your table, both percentage1 and 0 are 33.33 %